# Android image scale

Tags: android, image, layout, background, scale

I have a problem with my background, I will have some background with a color, and one image on the right bottom of the screen. Now i have a layout file. This is a relative layout. In this relative layout i place android:background="@drawable/background".

The following code is the code that i have placed in the background.xml. This file stays in the drawable folder.

This code doen't work right for me, the image is fullscreen. Can anyone help me? I am not very good with this.

The code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item android:id="@+id/background" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@drawable/lightgray"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/item_img"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY">

    <bitmap  
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</item>

</layer-list>
```

The relative layout from the startpage is here.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StartPage" >
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what im guessing, create a linear layout in the relative layout.. and you can then control is scalling..
and can you please post the actual layout(xml)
i would have posted this as a comment but i dont have enough reputation..

Try dis

```
<item 
  android:id="@+id/item_img"
  android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_parent" >

    <bitmap  
      android:src="@drawable/bg"
      android:layout_width="10dp"
      android:layout_height="10dp"
      android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</item>
```

try this approach..ive not tested it yet...

Comment: I have placed the linear layout too. Can anyone help me with this problem?